# How to know uploaded file size in grails?

Tags: grails

How to know uploaded file size in grails?
I want to show it on my screen, can you give one example how I can do that?

Here's I'm trying ${this.game.thumbnail.size()} but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="card-body">
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div class='fieldcontain required'>
                                                    <leve><b>Thumbnail details</b></leve>
                                                    <g:if test="${this.game.thumbnail}">
                                                        <img src="<g:createLink action='thumbnail' id='${this.game.id}' />" id="thumbnailFile" height="50" width="50" /></br>
                                                        <div class='fieldcontain required'>
                                                            <leve><b>Download Here</b></leve>
                                                            <g:link class="button" action="download" params="['id': this.game.id, type: 'thumbnail']" ><g:message code="Download" /></g:link>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class='fieldcontain required'>
                                                            <leve><b>Thumbnail File Size:</b></leve>
                                                         <leve>${this.game.thumbnail.size()}</leve>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </g:if>
                                                    <g:else>No Thumbnail details available</g:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` has a `.size()` method.

The guide at https://guides.grails.org/grails-upload-file/guide/index.html details how you can get a `MultipartFile`.